# Show even if $f$ is not one-to-one on $U$, the set $V=f[U]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, let $f \in \mathcal{C}^r(U: \mathbb{R}^n) ( r \geq 1)$, and assume that $Df(x)$ is invertible for every $x \in U$. Show even if $f$ is not one-to-one on $U$, the set $V=f[U]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Here is theorem: Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and let $ f \in \mathcal{C}^r(U;\mathbb{R}^n), r \geq 1.$ If $f$ is one-to-one and $Df(x)$ is an invertible matrix fo all $x \in U$, then $f[U] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f^{-1} \in \mathcal{C}^r(f[U];\mathbb{R}^n)$.

This problem is a bit self-contradictory to this theorem. I am not sure how to argue with that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Take any $y_0 \in f[U]$. Then, there is an $x_0\in U$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$. By hypothesis, $Df_{x_0}$ is invertible. So, you can use the inverse-function theorem around the point $x_0$

Comment: If $f$ is not one to one you cannot conclude much about $f^{-1}$ but you can still say something about $f(U)$. So the first claim is kind of a weaker version of the second.

Comment: You have to use the inverse function theorem. Finding the correct statement of the theorem is a first step.